# Excel Prevent overlapping of data labels in pie chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of dynamic pie charts in excel. I must use a pie chart, but my data labels(percentage, value, name) overlapping. How can I fix it except the best-fit option? [image]

Comment: My two cents, maybe not the answer you're expecting, but don't use a pie chart for this. Too many slices in a pie chart makes the chart unreadable.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but the client wants pie charts...

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/241459/prevent-excel-chart-data-labels-overlapping) link could be helpful.

Comment: unfortunately i tried the ones here

Comment: You could consider using a ['Pie of pie chart'](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1442-excel-create-pie-of-pie-chart.html).

Comment: its not helping too :(

Comment: Maybe this?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/explode-or-expand-a-pie-chart-63284b67-22ea-4960-ab1e-0a3895af68ce

Comment: thank you for the advice, I will ask the customer, Are they want to be sliced.